# Get userinfo from google OAuth API

Tags: node.js, express, google-oauth, google-api-nodejs-client

I want to get an user's information from the google OAuth api and save it to the database But I am getting only user's email address. I want user's firstname and lastname.

How can I do that?

The function:

```
google: async function (req) {
    var google = require("googleapis").google;
    var OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;
    var oauth2Client = new OAuth2();
    oauth2Client.setCredentials({ access_token: req.body.access_token });
    var oauth2 = google.oauth2({
      auth: oauth2Client,
      version: "v2",
    });
    oauth2.userinfo.get(async (err, res) => {
      if (err) {
      } else {
        console.log(res);
        let user_data = new User({
          first_name: res.data.given_name,
          last_name: res.data.family_name,
          email: res.data.email,
        });
        let user = await user_data.save();
        return user;
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: I would recommend going though the people api.  More data will be returned then you will get just from the userinfo endpoint.

Comment: I read that but I just can't understand that. There is too much of code

Comment: The user info endpoint is not going to return much of anything.  Mostly email.  If you want profile info then you need to go though the people api that's what its there for.    As for to much code, welcome to the world of software development we write a lot of code.